# Convert a default date to another date (local timezone of user)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a default time in the following format: `19 Jul : 7:00pm CST`

When a user visits the page where this time is displayed, I'd like it to be converted to the correct time according to the user's local time.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: some users don't really set their computer's time correctly...

Comment: That's fine -- I'll also give the choice to view the time in the 'default' time as well.

Comment: And whatever time they use on their computer is probably the right time to play with for websites, as they're on their computers when viewing websites anyway... Their time is their choice I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to output the date where you want it to appear, but be sure to specify its timezone (I use GMT here, but you could use UTC, etc). Then swap it out with the local time on load (Automatically handled by JavaScript if the original timezone is provided).

```
<div id="timestamp">April 21, 2014 6:00 pm GMT</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timestamp = document.getElementById('timestamp'),
        t         = new Date(timestamp.innerHTML),
        hours     = t.getHours(), 
        min       = t.getMinutes() + '', 
        pm        = false,
        months    = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    if(hours > 11){
       hours = hours - 12;
       pm = true;
    }

    if(hours == 0) hours = 12;
    if(min.length == 1) min = '0' + min;

    timestamp.innerHTML = months[t.getMonth()] + ' ' + t.getDate() + ', ' + t.getFullYear() + ' ' + hours + ':' + min + ' ' + (pm ? 'pm' : 'am');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could play with `.toLocaleTimeString()`

The `.toLocaleString()` method converts a `Date` object to a string, using locale settings.

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleString();
```

More about [Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)