# How to convert 2014-04-23T19:45:39 (UTC date) to AST date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a date like this:

`2014-04-23T19:45:39` which is a UTC format.

I want to convert it to AST format or the localize time zone of the user. How to do it?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by AST format?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23190699/257635. Does this help?

Comment: http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/asia/ast.html

Comment: http://momentjs.com/ - does a fair amount of localisation etc. Realise its an extra library, but its lovely.

something like
moment.tz("22014-04-23T19:45:39", "Asia/Baghdad").format();

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) library and just add or subtract number of hours that AST time have comparing to UTC.

```
new_date = date.add('hours',4);

or

new_date = date.subtract('hours',4);
```

Answer (score 0):

using  timezone-js. you can easily convert the time from one timeZone to another. [timezone.js](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js)

Answer (score 0):

```
var date_object;    
function localize(t){
      date_object=new Date(t+" UTC");
      document.write(date_object.toString());
}
localize("4/24/2014 4:52:48 PM")
document.write(date_object.toString().replace(/GMT.*/g,""));
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLuGr)